# VMware: How to get rid of "Moved it" and "Copied it" prompt?

Tags: windows-7, vmware-workstation

I have a few VMs that I am moving between two hosts every so often. Every single time VMware will prompt me whether I moved or whether I copied it (not affecting or affecting the MAC address respectively).

Since ACE was retired with VMware Workstation 8, how can I configure my VMs such that VMware will not prompt and assume either of the offered answers?

Affected VMware versions: VMware 9 and 8.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The VMware KB article [Changing or keeping a UUID for a moved virtual machine](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1541)
explains the concept of unique identifier (UUID) and offers
a solution that involves editing the VM configuration file (.vmx) and adding the line :

```
uuid.action = "keep"
```

This should always keep the existing unique identifier (UUID).

It is not specified starting from which version was this added to all VMware products.

Comment: I need to see whether this works for encrypted VMs, though. And whether it works on VMware Workstation at all. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Does the job, but one doesn't get around decrypting the VM end then re-encrypting it, it seems. Thanks.

Comment: I deal with creating multiple VMs over time - Isn't there a universal way to just disable the darn thing at the application level instead of having to going into the vmx everytime (after remembering to) ? I can understand this being required in production mode but in dev mode, who cares  - let it just assume it was copied. It changes the internal IP address anyway.

Comment: @killjoy: Some versions of VMware allow to select "Always Keep" in this dialog for this one VM, so avoids editing. I don't know of a general mechanism.